# Why Cassndra is called unstructured database

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Why Cassandra is called unstructured even though table/column family  has to be defined with columns and their data type.

For the defined table with some fixed columns we can choose to fill some columns in one particular row and choose not to fill in other row. But same thing can be done in RDBMS where we can leave some columns in the insert statement and the columns left out should allow null?

As mongo store the data in json documents where we can store different (keys) data every time insert new document. we don't need to define anything . But for cassandra we need to reconfigure our table to accommodate new columns getting added.

Even though some articles are present but still its not clear to me. Can someone pin point the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Basically is not about "how it works", is how the files are stored,  this is why cassandra have not structure for the files, you can have a same récords in diferents folders.